# How to display values from a custom attribute in magento 2?

Tags: custom-attributes, magento-2.1.3

I a problem on displaying the custom attribute and it's values in a custom phtml block.

Comment: Hi, please include the code you have already tried, and any error messages you have encountered. Please see ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for help on asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Attribute Value**

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('c_address')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

**Label**

```
$address =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('c_address')->getStoreLabel();
```

See the reference:

```
Magento/Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_product = $block->getProduct();

    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getCustomAttribute(), 'custom_attribute');
?>
```

**For eg.**

```
echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description');
```

Comment: Hi Abdul thanks for your answer. I'll try this one also.

Comment: Here's what I want to display. To create a dropdown menu  from the custom attribute for  manufacturers. and display the values of that manufacturer as a dropdown list of values in custom phtml file.